# Why show_in_app button is visible just for some models in rails admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

This is my **rails_admin.rb** file which I uncomment the `show_in_app` action as you see:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
      config.actions do
        dashboard  
        index                        
        new 
        export
        bulk_delete
        show_in_app
        show
        delete 
        edit
      end
end
```

but I don't understand why `show_in_app` action is available just for two of my models in rails admin dashboard ? I've tried to configure it like this for the models I necessarily need this action:

```
    show_in_app do
      only ['Model1','Model2']
    end
```

but it didn't work. I have the show action in my controller and show.html.erb in my views for these models.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I could not figure this out, seems that you will need to dig in the documentation https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Actions

Comment: The problem is this action is just available for some models not all of them.

Comment: and    `show_in_app do  only ['Model1','Model2']   end` does not work?

Comment: Yes it just works model model1!

Comment: did you solve this? i see this issue too